# Duration between two dates in SAS

Tags: sas

I will explain through an example-

suppose I have two dates and I want to find the duration between them in years month date format

```
start date= 19940412
end date= 20120326
```

duration of this 17 years 11 months 14 days.

So what code do i write to get this result in sas?

Comment: Are your dates stored as displayed, or as dates and formatted yyyymmdd?

Answer (score 3):

Here's the code you need:

```
data _null_;
   start_date= '19940412';
   end_date= '20120326';
   /* convert to sas dates */
   start_dt=input(start_date,yymmdd8.);
   end_dt=input(end_date,yymmdd8.);
   /* calculate difference in years */
   years=intck('YEAR',start_dt,end_dt,'C');
   /* recalculate start date */
   start_dt=intnx('YEAR',start_dt,years,'S');
   /* calculate remaining months */
   months=intck('MONTH',start_dt,end_dt,'C');
   /* recalculate start date */
   start_dt=intnx('MONTH',start_dt,months,'S');
   /* calculate remaining days */
   days=intck('DAY',start_dt,end_dt,'C');
   /* results */
   put years= months= days=;
run;
```

Which gives:

```
years=17 months=11 days=14
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the SAS function INTCK

For details, just search the internet for

```
 sas function intck
```

Comment: This won't provide output in the format requested by the OP